# Como é que eu posso saber se o primeiro digito de uma string é um número?

Tags: java, android, string

Eu tenho um formulário em que preciso de validar o **número de contribuinte**.

Se começar por `PT` ou se for um número sem uma sigla eu valido pelo algoritmo das finanças de Portugal, senão eu não valido.

O que eu queria saber é como é que eu sei se o primeiro digito da `string` do **número de contribuinte** é um número ou não?

Comment: Que falta não faz um `Integer.TryParse`.

Comment: Porquê a tag android?

Comment: @ramaral porque achei que poderia dar jeito a quem procurasse isso no android. É certo que é uma funcionalidade do Java seja ele qual for.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

É simples, precisa pegar o primeiro caractere e usar a função pronta [`isDigit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html).

```
Character.isDigit(x.charAt(0))
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/zCewrS). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/dlhpujao-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/String/IsDigit.java).

Atendendo a observação do utluiz no comentário abaixo, se a regra for considerar que o dígito sejam apenas números decimais arábicos, então é só fazer uma comparação simples:

```
x.charAt(0) >= '0' && x.charAt(0) <= '9'
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/iB1MzW). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/yyxnibqj-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/String/IsDigit2.java).

Obviamente pode colocar isso em um método genérico para usar em qualquer lugar. O método pode receber o caractere que deve ser analisado, o que deixa bem genérico, ou receber a *string* e o próprio método escolher o primeiro caractere, o que limita o uso ao exemplo citado na pergunta, mas evita trabalho extra na chamada.

Eu não iria por outras opções que não trarão ganhos, só prejuízos. [Fizeram um teste](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7461097/221800) com algumas delas em C#, o que deve resultar em algo semelhante ao do Java. Esta opção de verificar só os números arábicos deve ser ainda mais rápida, além de simples.

Comment: Na verdade, se você olhar a [documentação do método](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit-char-), vai perceber que *dígito* é um conceito mais genérico que *número*. Esse método vai incluir, por exemplo, [algarismos arábicos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Arabic_numerals) como [este](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0662/index.htm).

Comment: É, aí precisaria ter uma definição se isto pode ser incluído ou não como dígito.

Answer (score 22):

Se a ideia for verificar apenas números de `0` a `9`, o jeito mais simples, rápido e eficiente é:

```
character >= '0' && character <= '9'
```

Você pode criar uma rotina simples assim:

```
public class NumberUtils {
    public static boolean isNumber(char character) {
        return character >= '0' && character <= '9';
    }
}
```

E, talvez, adicionar uma outra rotina para verificar o caracter inicial, assim:

```
public static boolean startsWithNumber(String s) {
    return s != null && !s.isEmpty() && isNumber(s.charAt(0));
}
```

## Outras abordagens

### `Character.isDigit`

Se você olhar a [documentação do método](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit-char-), vai perceber que *dígito* é um conceito mais genérico que *número*.

Esse método vai incluir, por exemplo, [algarismos arábicos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Arabic_numerals) como [este](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0662/index.htm): ٢

### `Integer.parseInt`

Esse método funciona bem, mas somente é necessário para testar um número completo e não apenas um caractere.

### Google Guava

A biblioteca Guava tem o método estático [`Ints.tryParse(String)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#tryParse(java.lang.String)), que faz basicamente o mesmo que `Integer.parseInt`, mas sem lançar exceção. Se a String não for um número, `null` é retornado.

Entretanto, repito que, assim como o método acima este também é recomendado para números completos e não apenas um caracter.

### Expressão regular

Uma alternativa eficaz, porém mais lenta, mas que é útil principalmente se houver outros tipos de padrões.

Veja um exemplo:

```
public static boolean startsWithNumber(String s) {
    return s != null && s.matches("^\\d.*$");
}
```

Comment: Excelente resposta :)

Answer (score 12):

Pegue o primeiro dígito e tente convertê-lo. Se falhar, não começa com número. Algo assim:

```
public boolean primeiroDigitoEhUmNumero(String entrada) {
    String primeiroDigito = entrada.charAt(0) + "";
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(primeiroDigito);
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: É certo que funciona, mas não me parece boa ideia usar exceções para fazer comparações.

Comment: Também acho, mas não conhecia até agora a pouco `isDigit` . Vivendo e aprendendo. :)

Comment: é assim mesmo, sempre a aprender :)